# Interacting my lua app (LuaSocket) with my socket.io chat example server

Tags: lua, websocket, coronasdk, luasocket, gevent-socketio

I am writing an app for `Corona SDK` (Using LuaSocket) to be able to subscribe and post messages to the example chat server that runs in `socket.io` (using `gevent-websocket 0.9`).

I have checked that `chat.js` on the server interacts with ther server like this:

To subscribe to a room:

```
socket.subscribe('room-2000')
```

Or interacting with the chat room:

```
socket.send({room: 'room-2000', action: 'start', name: 'John'})

socket.send({room: 'room-2000', action: 'message', message: 'hi there!)});
```

etc..

[Full js client script.](https://bitbucket.org/stephenmcd/django-socketio/src/e72e9d6b13dd5e78168ffeae5d368924f6e307b5/django_socketio/example_project/chat/static/js/chat.js?at=default)

But I don't find a way to make an app for Corona SDK to interact with a channel. I managed to connect to the server with:

```
socket.connect( my_ip, my_port)
```

But cannot find a way to subscribe or post/receive messages, can someone give me a clue? Will be highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you need to do a WebSocket handshake. Read the WebSocket specifiation.
Otherwise, I can recommend you this Publish/Subscribe library for CoronaSDK/Nodejs
https://github.com/Overtorment/NoobHub